# Python program to determine whether a password meets all the requirements for a secure password

Tags: python

I need help with my coding. Some of it is incorrect and I am not sure where to begin. Here is what is required in my program. "Writing a Python program to determine whether a password meets all the requirements for a secure password. Your program should prompt the user for the candidate password and output either that the password is valid or the reason it is invalid. To be valid the length of the password must greater than some minimum length but less than some maximum. It must not include the substring "umgc" in any combination of upper or lower case letters. Finally, it must contain the # symbol in some position other than the first or last character. You should decide on the minimum and maximum allowable lengths."

```
password=input("Enter password:")
if 'u''m''g''c' in password:
    print('invalid')
elif len <=1:
    print('invalid')
elif len >=4:
    print('invalid')
else password[0:3])
    print('valid')
```

Comment: You should begin with reviewing your lecture notes and comparing the examples with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check @Meatforge explanation it's really well written. I'll try to cover other things that I wrote inside my code.

```
def password_checker():
    password = input("Enter password: ")
    if len(password) > 5 and len(password) < 10: #password lenght
        print("Password lenght - Valid")
    else:
        return print("Password lenght - Invalid")
    if "umgc" not in password.lower():
        print('Substring "umgc" in password check - Valid')
    else:
        return print('Substring "umgc" in password check - Invalid')
    if "#" in password[1:-1]:
        print('Looking for "#". Check - Valid')
    else:
        return print('Looking for "#". Check - Invalid')
    print("Your password is secure!")
    
password_checker()
```

First of all, I think you should make it into function, even though it's a really small program it's a good habit for the future and you can use the `return` method which will stop further execution of your function.

**password.[lower()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/lower)** - changes your string into lowercase (ignores letters that are already lowercase. You can also use [.upper()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/upper)). Now, no matter how you'll write "ugmc" it will change it to lowercase.

**if "#" in password[1:-1]** - removes first and the last letter from your string and checks if "#" is inside it.

**print("Your password is secure!")** - you will get this message only after all checks were valid. Why? Even though I didn't use any if/else statement if any check was invalid it would exit from my function earlier with the `return` statement.

I hope everything is clear. If you have any questions don't hesitate. :D

Comment: This was very helpful thank you. I am so new to python that I don't think about making it a function. That makes complete sense. And thank you for explaining things, it helps me to learn!

Comment: Glad to help, but if you are not making it into function remember to change the `return` statement to something else, because it won't work outside the function and add some if/else before `print("Your password is secure!")`.

Answer (score 0):

So let's unpack this issue. Syntax first.

"len" is a function that counts the number of elements in a variable. Either characters in a string or elements in a list. To use it, you need to give it an argument. If you just say "len", python won't know what you're trying to count.
You're going to want to change your empty "len" to this.

```
elif len(password) <= 1:
    print('invalid')

elif len(password) >= 4:
    print('invalid')
```

Now let's cover "else". Else is a statement that doesn't require any additional parameters. It basically means, "If none of the above situations apply, do this." Remember to add a colon to any "if", "elif", or "else" statements.
To fix, simply change your "else" to this:

```
else:
print("valid")
```

As for the substring issue. Do you mean that the password can't contain any individual one of those characters? If so, then your first if statement is fine. If you meant, however, that it can't contain any combination of that string of characters, then you would want to code this a bit differently. Your current solution prevents the user from including either "u", "m", "g", or "c" in the final password. Not to mention, you didn't prohibit the capitalized versions of those characters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking 'u''m''g''c', maybe check 'umgc', and then that would be correct
Check first if '#' and then check if its in the first place or last place. After the password has passed all of those parameters, then you can return Valid. C:

Ask me if you need any more help and have a great day! C:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).